# How do I generate .csv header on first line only?

Tags: vb.net, csv, export-to-csv

How do I use VB.NET code to generate a .csv header on the first line only? Below is the code I tried, but it wrote on top and column of the .csv file.

```
Try
    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\bin\Debug\TimerTest.csv",
        "Date and Time,Tag Name, Value" & vbCrLf & 
        timeUtc & "," & Tag_name_Read & "," & itemValues(0).Value.ToString, True) 
    'Date and Time, Tag Name, Value are my header. they are suppose to be on the first line

Catch ex As Exception
End Try

If daServerMgt.IsConnected Then
    daServerMgt.Disconnect()
End If
```

[Update Link Showing the csv file)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUiz2.png)

I just want the header (Date and Time | Tag Name | Value) on top, I don't want it on the column. It is appending it because of the  My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(File, Text, true)

How do I fix this?

Comment: I don't think that what you do is writing true csv file. Why don't you use some established code,  like **lumenworks** csv library?

Comment: It seems like this should work, though.  @Smoky2016, would you please update your question so as to show us the exact contents of the CSV file after the code runs?

Comment: Please don't ever do `Catch ex As Exception` - it's bad. Only put code in a `Try`/`Catch` if you are catching a specific exception that you can recover from.

Comment: @ MJH, unfortunately I am not at my project station at the moment. I will be able to run the code on Monday (10/31/16) and post the result.

Comment: @ MJH here is my dilemma, I just want the header (Date and Time | Tag Name | Value) on top, I don't want it on the column. It is appending it because of the  My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(File, Text, true)

Comment: @ MJH I have update the question to show the csv file, I just want the header (Date and Time | Tag Name | Value) on top, I don't want it on the column. It is appending it because of the  My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(File, Text, true)

Comment: @ MJH I have update the question to show the csv file, I just want the header (Date and Time | Tag Name | Value) on top, I don't want it on the column. It is appending it because of the  My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(File, Text, true). I want every other data appending, not the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just find the solution by adding the header’s text into the `Run_Click` sub. Which in turn will append the text into the existing file and place it on the first line (header row), every time you run the event. It work!

Below is the code I used:

```
Private Sub Run_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Run.Click
    Dim Path As String = "C:\bin\Debug\TimerTest.csv"

    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(Path, "Date and Time, Tag Name, Value", False) 'add
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from issues such as the one @Enigmativity mentioned, there doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your code.

My old machine crashed very recently, and I don't yet have Visual Studio installed on my brand new machine, but I created a file in my `C:\Temp` folder called `TimerTest.vb`, with the following contents:

```
Imports System

Module Module1
    Public Structure Struct1
        Public Value As Integer
        Sub New(ByVal _Value As Integer)
            Value = _Value
        End Sub
    End Structure 

    Sub Main()
        Dim timeUtc As DateTime = DateTime.Now()
        Dim Tag_name_Read As String = "FortyTwo"
        Dim itemValues = New Struct1() { New Struct1(42), New Struct1(43), New Struct1(44)}

        Try
            'My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\bin\Debug\TimerTest.csv",
            My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\Temp\TimerTest.csv",
                "Date and Time,Tag Name, Value" & vbCrLf & 
                timeUtc & "," & Tag_name_Read & "," & itemValues(0).Value.ToString, True) 
            'Date and Time, Tag Name, Value are my header. they are suppose to be on the first line

        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try

        'If daServerMgt.IsConnected Then
        '    daServerMgt.Disconnect()
        'End If
    End Sub
End Module
```

I then compiled by running the following statement in a Command Window (`vbc.exe`'s parent folder is already in my `%PATH%`):

```
vbc C:\Temp\TimerTest.vb
```

After I ran the resulting `TimerTest.exe` file, a `TimerTest.csv` file was generated in `C:\Temp`, with the following contents:

```
Date and Time,Tag Name, Value<br>
10/27/2016 9:07:31 PM,FortyTwo,42
```

When I double-click the `TimerTest.csv` file, it opens in Excel without any issue:

[image]

Therefore, the problem must be elsewhere in your code. So as to make it easier for us to help you, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that will replicate the issue.